# IIS Application Crash Dump File Assistance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crash, iis-7.5

I am looking for some assistance understanding some of my w3p crash dump file.

Back ground info:  I have an IIS 7.5 .net 4.5 application (WebApiApplication) that is setup to be a background services application.  The application is set to always on.  The application is crashing / unloading at intermittent spots and I am troubleshooting the crash with a dump file.  When the application crashes, the Application_End() event fires, but the event handler I attach to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException does not.  That lead me to believe I have some kind of memory leak or process dead lock issue.  I've profiled my application with memory dumps and ants profile and no real problems that indicated a memory leak showed up.

I have my w3p process debugged with the debug diagnostic tool.  Here are some concerning areas:

This log event shows up every few seconds which makes no sense.  This is during a period where there is no IIS log activity on the application, so the application is doing this without external requests.  This happens several every second to every few seconds for hours before the crash. This is very strange to me because this is a c# application and there is no VB code whatsoever.  I'm logging all of my code events where I start and close new tasks and threads, and these events do not correlate with any of my code, it looks like a managed code issue?

```
[10/26/2014 8:52:36 PM] First chance exception - 0XE0434352 caused by thread with Script Error
Error Code - 0x800A0005
Error Source [Microsoft VBScript runtime error]
Error Description [Invalid procedure call or argument]
Line 458, Column 10

[10/26/2014 8:52:37 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4912. Exit code -     0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:41 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5696
[10/26/2014 8:52:43 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5696. Exit code -     0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:44 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7640
[10/26/2014 8:52:47 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7640. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:48 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7584
[10/26/2014 8:52:50 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7584. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:50 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5760
[10/26/2014 8:52:53 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5760. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:55 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7056
[10/26/2014 8:52:57 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7056. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:52:58 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 6324
[10/26/2014 8:53:00 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 6324. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:01 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3080
[10/26/2014 8:53:03 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3080. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:03 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7052
[10/26/2014 8:53:04 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7052. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:05 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4796
[10/26/2014 8:53:07 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4796. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:08 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 1548
[10/26/2014 8:53:10 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 1548. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:11 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 6492
[10/26/2014 8:53:12 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 6492. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:13 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4484
[10/26/2014 8:53:14 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7520. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:14 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2196
[10/26/2014 8:53:15 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4484. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:16 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 6452
[10/26/2014 8:53:17 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 6452. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:20 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4312
[10/26/2014 8:53:22 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4312. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:22 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5740
[10/26/2014 8:53:23 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5740. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:25 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7908
[10/26/2014 8:53:27 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 7908. Exit code -     0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:28 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5996
[10/26/2014 8:53:30 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5996. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:31 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4400
[10/26/2014 8:53:33 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4400. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:33 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5168
[10/26/2014 8:53:34 PM] Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5168. Exit code - 0x00000000
[10/26/2014 8:53:35 PM] Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 7620
[10/26/2014 8:53:35 PM] First chance exception - 0XE0434352 caused by thread with System ID: 5324Script Error
```

Another area of concern is that all the dlls in my bin directory load like this:

```
[10/26/2014 6:11:20 PM] My.dll loaded at 0x52530000
[10/26/2014 6:11:20 PM] My.dll loaded at 0x05280000
[10/26/2014 6:11:20 PM] My.dll Unloaded from 0x52530000
```

Is this an issue to see the dll loaded twice and then unloaded from the memory register, or is this expected?

I have everything in my application logged six ways from Sunday, and I just can't figure out this intermittent application crash issue, any clues?

Comment: Tried looking @ Server.GetLastError() in Application_Error() ?

Comment: Alek -- Not specifically, but wouldn't that be logged in my w3p dump?  My crash rule is set to stackoverflow, exceptions and first chance exceptions.

Comment: 0xE0434352 is a .NET exception. Note that first chance exceptions are not necessarily bad. They can be caught and handled.

Comment: Loading a DLL several times can happen if your application (or IIS itself, I'm not so familiar with it) uses application domains. The only way to unload a .NET DLL is to load it in an application domain and then destroy the application domain.

Comment: Thomas W I agree that they aren't bad when understood and handled, but I'm trying to track down an intermittent crash, and an unexplained first chance exception firing every second for hours seems like a good place to look. Also I'm only running one app domain here, so I don't see why the dll would unload and load multiple times.